# Problem with JSON_TABLE function in MYSQL 5.7.26

Tags: mysql, json, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that changes rows into columns here:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `pivot`(tablename VARCHAR(10000),
                        groupname VARCHAR(64),
                        groupname2 VARCHAR(64),
                        groupname3 varchar(64),
                        groupname4 varchar(64),
                        groupname5 varchar(64),
                        pivotname VARCHAR(64),
                        valuename  VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
SELECT CONCAT('CREATE VIEW to_columnslist AS\n',
              'SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(\'`\', `', pivotname,'`, \'` VARCHAR(255) path \\\'$."\', ', pivotname,', \'"\\\'\') line\n',
              'FROM (', tablename, ') a')
INTO @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DROP PREPARE stmt;
SELECT CONCAT(
'SELECT to_json.`', groupname,'`,`',groupname2,'`,`',groupname3,'`,`',groupname4,'`,`',groupname5,'`, parsed.*', '\n',
'FROM (SELECT `', groupname,'`,`',groupname2,'`,`',groupname3,'`,`',groupname4,'`,`',groupname5,'`, JSON_OBJECTAGG(`', pivotname,'`, `', valuename,'`) json_data', '\n',
'      FROM (', tablename,') a', '\n',
'      GROUP BY `', groupname,'`,`',groupname2,'`,`',groupname3,'`,`',groupname4,'`,`',groupname5,'`  ORDER BY `',groupname2,'` DESC) to_json', '\n',
'CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE( json_data,', '\n',
'                       "$" COLUMNS ( ', 
GROUP_CONCAT(line SEPARATOR ',\n                                     '),
' ) ) parsed'
) sql_text
INTO @sql
FROM to_columnslist;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DROP PREPARE stmt;
DROP VIEW to_columnslist;
END
```

What this procedure does is change the appearance of the data from this:
[image: Before Pivot]

To this:

[image: After Pivot]

**Problem**: We are required to use MYSQL 5.7 instead of MYSQL 8. The result is that when trying to call the 'pivot' procedure in MYSQL 5.7, the webapp throws the following error:

```
Get_QueryResultSet Error :
SP_GET_CODEDESC(?,?,?) com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( json_data,
                           "$" COLUMNS ( `Cash` VARCHAR(255) path '$."C' at line 11
```

Based on what the error displays, we can see the problem lies in this part of the procedure:
[image]

Are there any alternatives to using JSON_TABLE? Cannot upgrade to MYSQL 8, so will need to find another way to run this part of the procedure somehow.

Tried replacing the code in the red block with this:

```
'CROSS JOIN (SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json_data2, ', '$[*].Cash',') AS Cash,
JSON_EXTRACT(json_data2, ','$[*].Low',') AS Low,
JSON_EXTRACT(json_data2, ','$[*].Medium',') AS Medium,
JSON_EXTRACT(json_data2, ','$[*].High',') AS High
FROM (SELECT CAST(json_data AS JSON) AS json_data2) AS jt) parsed'
```

but it returns the following error:

```
Get_QueryResultSet Error :
SP_GET_CODEDESC(?,?,?) com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Result consisted of more than one row
```

The fix that I attempted to use isn't even the best because I have to hardcode the descriptions in (Cash, Low, Medium, High). In reality, users are able to add and remove price buckets, which means there may be more or less buckets to deal with.

So there needs to be a way to:

- Replace JSON_TABLE with something compatible with MYSQL 5.7
- Needs to work with dynamically changing data

Not sure where to go from here tbh...

Comment: 5.7 reaches end of life in October and will no longer get security updates.  You should consider it insecure then.  Being "required to use MYSQL 5.7" is no longer a reasonable position.

Comment: XY-problem. Post the task itself according to [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055).

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to look for a replacement for the JSON_TABLE function. Currently I'm trying to see if I can create a table using the results from JSON_OBJECTAGG, still a work in progress atm.